# Close connection if there is an error 'connection not closed'?

Tags: vb.net

My `vb.net` application shows an error.

`Connection not closed. Connection's  current state is open`
Here is my code. Please help me rectify the error:

```
Private Sub saveBtn_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles          saveBtn.Click
        addSubject()
       End Sub

    Private Function addSubject() As Boolean
      Dim cmd As New SqlCommand
      Dim ok As Boolean = False
      cmd.Connection = con
      cmd.CommandText = " INSERT INTO Subjects(subject_name) VALUES(@inn)"
      cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
      cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("inn", subjectTxt.Text)

      Try
        con.Open()
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        ok = True

      Catch ex As Exception
          MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Add failed")
         ok = False
       End Try
      cmd.Dispose()
      con.Close()
      Return ok

      con.Close()
    End Function
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There might be an open connection in your previous codes in which you were not able to close it.

This connection state checker could help you:

```
If connection.State <> 1
connection.Open()
End IF
```

Answer (score 0):

wrap sqlcommand in a [using](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/htd05whh.aspx) statement.  Don't call close or dispose manually.

Answer (score 0):

Try to check connection state before opening, no need to open connection if it has already opened :

```
If con.State <> ConnectionState.Open Then
    con.Open()
End If
```

That will help you avoid current exception.

Anyway, root cause of this problem could be somewhere else. Because, your code already tried to close connection in the end, so it seems that there is another part of your program that is not closing the connection properly.

Possible solution is not to share your connection object, instantiate new connection every time needed and wrap it around `using` statement as also pointed by @DeveloperGuo.